# Excel VBA: How to pass one element of a type structure to a function in vba

Tags: excel, vba, function, structure

I have a structure defined in a module as follows:

```
Type Assets
   Tags() As String
   Names() As String
End Type
Public Assets() As Assets
```

`Assets(x).Tags(0..n)` holds a number of items of text to make up a location string.
`Assets(x).Names(0..n)` holds the corresponding "readable" names for these tags.
The array `Assets(x)` is populated from a worksheet, such that there is a unique value of x for each line in the spreadsheet.
There may be duplicates in the `Tags()` data, so I need to pass a list to a function to remove the duplication. Therein lies the issue.
How can I pass `Assets(0..n).Tags(y)` to a function to have it drop into something like:

```
Public Function RemoveDuplicates(ByRef InputList() As String, ByRef OutputList() As String) As Integer
```

@user3598756 has answered this, but just for interest:
Reading my spreadsheet into the `Assets()` array, I begin this bit with

```
Assets(1).Tags(1)="PRESS"
Assets(1).Tags(2)="DR1"
Assets(1).Tags(3)="HP1"
Assets(2).Tags(1)="PRESS"
Assets(2).Tags(2)="DR1"
Assets(2).Tags(3)="HP2"
Assets(3).Tags(1)="OUTP"
Assets(3).Tags(2)="DR1"
Assets(3).Tags(3)="SV1"
```

I need to, amongst other things, load a listbox with `Assets(x).Tags(1)`, to give me:

    `PRESS
    OUTP`
for the user to select from. Based on this selection, I then move on to `Assets(x).Tag(2)` etc, such that my list (`myTags` in @user3598756's code) is progressively reduced to a unique selection.

Comment: your narrative is confusing me. for instance _"The array Assets(x) is populated from a worksheet, such that there is a unique value of x for each line in the spreadsheet"_ doesn't make sense since being `x` an array index it is unique by definition. you may want to post some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just guessing out of Axel Richter answeer

you could have this function:

```
    Public Function RemoveDuplicates(myAssets() As Assets, yTag As Long, OutputList As Variant) As Integer
        Dim iAsset As Long

        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            For iAsset = LBound(myAssets) To UBound(myAssets)
                .Item(myAssets(iAsset).Tags(yTag)) = .Item(myAssets(iAsset).Tags(yTag))
            Next
            OutputList = .keys
            RemoveDuplicates = .Count
        End With
    End Function
```

that you can call from your "main" code like follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim Assets() As Assets '<--| declare 'Asset' as a Sub scoped variable and then pass it to other subs as an argument
    Dim myTags As Variant '<--| this will be passed to 'RemoveDuplicates()' function to be "transformed" into the the array (a 'Variant' can be that) holding unique tags for the specified tag index
    Dim myInt As Integer '<--| this will store the returned integer value from 'RemoveDuplicates()' function

   'example of filling Assets
    ReDim Assets(0 To 2) As Assets
    With Assets(0)
        ReDim .Tags(0 To 1)
        .Tags(0) = "tag1"
        .Tags(1) = "tag2"
    End With
    With Assets(1)
        ReDim .Tags(0 To 1)
        .Tags(0) = "tag2"
        .Tags(1) = "tag3"
    End With
    With Assets(2)
        ReDim .Tags(0 To 1)
        .Tags(0) = "tag1"
        .Tags(1) = "tag2"
    End With

    myInt = RemoveDuplicates(Assets, 1, myTags) '<--| have 'myTags' returned as an array with unique tags out of 'Assets(0...n).Tags(1)': namely it'll return a two elements array containing "tag1" and "tag2". Thus myInt will be 2
End Sub
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, at least the end result is. I'd not discovered the Scripting.Dictionary, so I didn't know to look for it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Assets` is an array of `Asset`s where each `Asset` has `Tags` as an array of `Strings`. So there is not a direct access to get an array containing a specific tag string from each `Asset`. You have to get it by looping over all `Asset`s.

```
Type Assets
   Tags() As String
   Names() As String
End Type
Public Assets() As Assets

Sub main()
 Dim i As Long, j As Long
 For i = 0 To 2
  ReDim Preserve Assets(i)
  For j = 0 To 2
   ReDim Preserve Assets(i).Tags(j)
   Assets(i).Tags(j) = "T" & j + 1 & " from Asset " & i
  Next
 Next

 Dim aInputList() As String
 Dim aOutputList() As String

 Dim y As Long
 y = 1

 For i = LBound(Assets) To UBound(Assets)
  ReDim Preserve aInputList(i)
  aInputList(i) = Assets(i).Tags(y)
 Next

 Dim v As Integer
 v = RemoveDuplicates(aInputList, aOutputList)

End Sub

Public Function RemoveDuplicates(ByRef InputList() As String, ByRef OutputList() As String) As Integer
 Dim s As Variant
 For Each s In InputList
  MsgBox s
 Next
 RemoveDuplicates = 1
End Function
```